# Does Strongloop oracle loopback connector supports Oracle DB encryption policies?

Tags: node.js, strongloop

I have an application on Loopback and Oracle 12c DB.
I have enabled security package on Oracle RDBMS for channel encryption, I want to know if loopback oracle connector has some configuration which enables channel encryption from the loopback connector client as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I have enabled security package on Oracle RDBMS for channel encryption

What does this mean? What exactly did you do?

Loopback uses node-oracledb. See the doc for that module on enabling network encryption:
https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#securenetwork

Also, see slides 18-31 here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/69jt5uu1fqus84c/Tips%20and%20Tricks%20for%20Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20Oracle%20Database%20Driver%20for%20Node.pdf?dl=0